# pointer to run a function which variables are the variables of a structure

Tags: c, function, pointers, struct

In the code below, I use a pointer to run a function which variables are the variables of a structure. When I run the function `(*foo)(numbers)`, I get the message `" 24:1: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration [enabled by default]"` and if I put the name of the structure together with the variable `(*foo)(sum_elements numbers)` I get lots of errors What is it lacking to not get the warning message?

```
#include<stdio.h>

struct sum_elements{                //structure declaration
int number1,number2,sum_result,*foo;
}numbers; 

void Sum_operator(struct sum_elements numbers){     //structure's function declaration

numbers.sum_result = numbers.number2 + numbers.number1;
printf("The sum is %d",numbers.sum_result); 

}

int main(){

printf("Enter first number: "); 
scanf("%d",&numbers.number1); 

printf("Enter second number:"); 
scanf("%d",&numbers.number2); 

void (*foo)(numbers);               //pointer to function declaration
foo = &Sum_operator;
    (*foo)(numbers);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Declare the function pointer like this, with the parameter type:

```
void (*foo)(struct sum_elements);
```

Answer (score 1):

For added convenience you can add typedef for the type of function pointer.
e.g.

```
typedef void (*MYFUNC)(struct sum_elements) ;

MYFUNC foo = &Sum_operator ;
foo( numbers ) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare a [pointer to a function](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html) you must provide the retruned type and the arguments types. This pointer cannot point to a function that's has a different returned type or arguments types.

In your case the declaration must be like this:

```
void (*functionPointer)(struct sum_elements);
```